# How to scroll a TVertscrollBox with a TListbox inside

Tags: delphi, listbox, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

I have some components inside a TVertScroll, inside there is also a tListBox with ListStyle = horizontal.

Screen scrolling works up or down correctly when selecting the other components, except when I select the TListbox.

Does anyone have any idea how to transfer the screen scroll control up or down when TListBox is selected for the TVertScroll.

Comment: I think you need to provide more details. Please edit your post and add a [mre]. Most importantly the `.fmx` content, so we can see the relation between components and their settings. Cut down your example to the minimum that reproduces the problem, including the events related to scrolling.

Comment: I edited the tags and removed corresponding info from the title. The tagging system works well on this site, and is therefore preferred instead of writing that info in the title or text. Concerning FMX projects, it might be a good idea to indicate target platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I just add GestureManager to ListBox and set this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJqHp.png
so UP and DOWN gestures must be checked.
It allow to scroll up and down

Comment: Please also describe what you did. Not everybody can see images.